# jQuery, php and Ajax issue: Can't make dynamic link load dynamic content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

There's a great [tutorial on IBM's website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/index.html) which walked me through a simple search/results list using jQuery,PHP and Ajax.

I was able to make it work and it's really cool.

One problem.  I want the results to be hyperlinks and I can't get any java script to run on the results.

Here is the script I have (includes what was in the tutorial plus the additional script necessary to ovverride the hyperlink, click behavior):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#search_results").slideUp();
$("#search_button").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
ajax_search();
});
$("#search_term").keyup(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
ajax_search();
});
$("a").click(ClickInterceptor);
});

function ajax_search(){
$("#search_results").show();
var search_val=$("#search_term").val();
$.post("./find.php", {search_term : search_val}, function(data){
if (data.length>0){
$("#search_results").html(data);
}
})
}

function ClickInterceptor(e)
{
window.alert("Hellow World!");
return false;
}
</script>
```

If i put the following html under the `<body>` tag:

```
<a href="test">this will work</a>
```

That will display the alert window.

However, if I change the results to hyperlinks (found in **find.php, listing 7** from the tutorial):

```
$string .= "<a href=\"test\">".$row->name."</a> - ";
```

It does not work.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `click` function binds when it is run. You need to change it to a [live binding](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).

```
$("a").live("click", ClickInterceptor);
```

Or you can just bind it when you update the search results by putting the following after `$("#search_results").html(data)`:

```
$("#search_results a").click(ClickInterceptor);
```

Comment: well, apparently, I don't have enough reputation to vote up.  But swapping to live binding did the trick.  
I'm sure the others would have too.
tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty simple actually, `$("a").click(ClickInterceptor);` will only look for items that currently exist in the DOM.  All you need to do is change that line to this:

```
$("a").live("click", ClickInterceptor);
```

I'd also advise taking the time to read more about [jQuery's Events/live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).